# Why is my recurssion not working? Warning: Project Euler spoiler

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm not quite sure why my recursive algorithm is not working. I get the below error but, i guess in my mind it appears i have a termination point. I know I am forgetting something simple.

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

```
def triplet(n):
    a = (2*n) +1
    b = (2*n)*(n+1)
    c = (2*n)*(n+1) +1

    if a+b+c == 1000:
        return a*b*c
    elif a+b+c > 1000:
        return 'no triplet found'
    else:
        return triplet(n+1)

print triplet(1)
```

Comment: What if no `n` exists for which `a+b+c == 1000`?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem my friend Alex, the only way out of this is when a + b + c == 1000

Comment: Also, if a+b+c > 1000 you can safely stop searching for your triplet.

Comment: Python doesn't recognize tail recursion and your approach is as naturally iterative as can be.

Comment: This was made for iteration, not recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a variant of Euclid's method for generating triples.  However, it does not produce ALL possible triples, and so it clearly not generating the triples that are needed to solve your problem.

In fact, there is no universal formula for generating all Pythagorean triples.  You'll need to either analytically find the solution or brute force it.

Comment: Sure.  Also, repeating what others said, this problem calls for iteration and not recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Check for greater then or equals

```
def triplet(n):
    a = (2 * n) + 1
    b = (2 * n) * (n + 1)
    c = (2 * n) * (n + 1) + 1

    if a + b + c >= 1000:
        return a * b * c
    else:
        return triplet(n + 1)

print triplet(1)
```

Comment: `a * b * c` is regarded as a solution to the problem - you should instead add another conditional to return an error value such as -1 if `a + b + c > 1000`.  Also, this solves the recursion error, but not the problem itself.

Comment: I don't know what problem its trying to solve but the question was 'Why is my recurssion not working?', Because it had no way out unless a + b + c was exactly 1000, so this solved the recursion error, the problem itself is an entirely different question to what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure recursion/euclid's method is the best way to go about doing this one? I remember doing this by holding the sum equal to 1000, and then varying the two independent variables and checking when they were equal. (I also used some sort of the triangle inequality to decrease the number of solutions to check, but that is not necessary as at most you'll be checking 1 million possibilities).